# LibGDX Orthographic camera not rendering at certain angles

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx

I'm currently experimenting with different cameras in libgdx (using ShapeRenderer). However I've found that at certain rotations it stops rendering segments of the shape.

For example the normal shape with camera
Position: (8.999996,7.699995,5.599995)
Direction: (0.04838332,-0.60004705,-0.7576189):

[image: normal_shape]

However with camera
Position: (8.999996,7.699995,5.0999956)
Direction: (0.6789076,-0.57323986,-0.38322547):

[image: cutoff_shape]

As far as I'm aware this does not occur on PerspectiveCamera (I haven't tested it extensively though so I might be wrong).

**Code snippets**

Aux. Info:

```
VIEWPORT_WIDTH = 20;
VIEWPORT_HEIGHT = 13;
gridDist = 1.2f;
```

The x and y for each tile is an Integer (like a grid).

Setting up camera (I am using Scene2D.Stage):

```
public MainStage(){

        super(new ScalingViewport(Scaling.stretch, VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT, new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight())));
        camera = (OrthographicCamera) this.getCamera();
        camera.direction.set(0f, 0.3f,-0.92f);
        camera.position.set(10f,0f,10f);
        camera.update();
}
```

Drawing Tiles (X/Y coordinates) :

```
renderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

renderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
renderer.setColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
for(GridTile[] trow: room.tiles){
    for(GridTile tile: trow){

        if(tile.status != EMPTY){


            if(tile.status == FULL){
                renderer.rect(tile.x*gridDist, tile.y*gridDist, gridDist, gridDist);

            }
            else if(tile.status == UP_RIGHT){
                renderer.triangle((tile.x+1)*gridDist, tile.y*gridDist, (tile.x+1)*gridDist, (tile.y+1)*gridDist, (tile.x)*gridDist, (tile.y+1)*gridDist);

            }
            else if(tile.status == DOWN_RIGHT){
                renderer.triangle((tile.x)*gridDist, tile.y*gridDist, (tile.x+1)*gridDist, (tile.y)*gridDist, (tile.x+1)*gridDist, (tile.y+1)*gridDist);
            }
            else if(tile.status == DOWN_LEFT){
                renderer.triangle((tile.x)*gridDist, tile.y*gridDist, (tile.x+1)*gridDist, (tile.y)*gridDist, (tile.x)*gridDist, (tile.y+1)*gridDist);
            }
            else if(tile.status == UP_LEFT){
                renderer.triangle((tile.x)*gridDist, tile.y*gridDist, (tile.x+1)*gridDist, (tile.y+1)*gridDist, (tile.x)*gridDist, (tile.y+1)*gridDist);
            }
        }     
    }
}
renderer.end();
```

Does anyone know why this occurs and if it is possible to prevent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably due to your image being too close to the camera and is being clipped. You could try and move the plane away from the camera.

Comment: like dfour said, but I give you another way, you could also set the clipping distance to very near, according to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera only renders elements between the near and far planes.  [image: OpenGL near and far planes]

The default values are 0 (near) and 100 (far) in a orthographic camera , the values correspond to the distance between the plane and the camera, according to the documentation they must be positive https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Camera.html#near but I have tried negative values without problems (plane located behind the camera)

The far and near values can be easily modified

```
camera.near = 1f;
camera.far = 50f;
```